# Чи є правильним вживати слово "авіатроща"?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Все частіше в ЗМІ зустрічається слово ***"авіатроща"***, коли повідомляють про авіаційну катастрофу.

> В [Словнику скорочень української мови](http://ukrskor.info/?text=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) для словосполучення *"авіаційна катастрофа"* присутнє слово ***"авіакатастрофа"***.

Звідки взялося ***"авіатроща"***? Яке має походження дане слово?

Answer (score 2):

Московсько-український словник. 1918. Дубровський.

> Крушеніе - крушнява, загин, руйнацтво.

Етимологічний словник української мови. 2006. Том 5.

> Трощити - див. троск. Троск - ляскання батога. Удар, тріск, шум.
>   Трощити - ламати, розбивати, жадібно їсти.

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. 2005. Бусел.

> Троща - очерет.
>
> Трощення - дія, за значенням трощити.

[Активні запити](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=UA&q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0) цього слова в Ґуґлі почалися з 2015 року у Львівській області.

Comment: Мені чомусь подекуди, коли вибрати _увесь сьвіт_, викидає 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Це слово використовують деякі недобросовісні ЗМІ, особливо в Інтернеті. Вони здійснюють машинний переклад з російської мови, після чого, навіть, не обтяжують себе прочитати такий переклад, хоча б один раз. Походить це слово від російського "авиакрушение", де "авиа" перекладається як "авія", а "крушение" – "троща", тому що "крушить" – це "трощити". Ось і виходить таке дивне слово.

Comment: Ваша теорія виглядала б правдоподібною, якби не дві речі. (1) ЗМІ використовують слово «троща» і щодо автомобільних аварій, а не лише авіа- чи корабельних (але ж російською мовою не кажуть «крушение» про автомобільні аварії, принаймні я ніколи не чув); (2) слово «[троща](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=троща&dicts=1&highlight=on)» є у старих словниках 1930-х (тож це не породжений-машинним-перекладом неологізм — а радше чиясь свідома (вдала чи невдала — важко судити) спроба відродити старе слово (можливо, в трішки зміненому значенні)).

Comment: Навряд це машинний переклад, але цілком можливо, що це калька/відповідник російського «крушение». Спочатку з'явилося «кораблетроща», а нещодавно і «авіатроща».

Comment: @Sasha, а от наявність слова «троща» у значенні «трощення» в словнику Кримського-Єфремова не значить, що це слово колись було у вжитку. Зверніть увагу, що це слово наводить **лише** даний словник. Ні в Грінченка, ні в інших старих словниках його немає, тому найімовірніше, це авторський неологізм Кримського, яких там багато.

Comment: @OhneKleidung, маєте рацію. В старих книжках бачу слово _трощити_, але _троща_ вживається здебільшого як назва рослини, жодного _троща_ в значенні «трощення» не знайшов. (Але в будь-якому разі це не машинний переклад — а спроба відродити слово з 1930-х, хай навіть це слово тоді було створене штучно й не прижилося.)

Comment: Отже, це слово не дуже доречне? Так само, як і _кораблетроща_?